# how can i detect routing in angular to set a variable?

Tags: angular, angular6

i have a parent component as shown in the code below that i simplified. i want to set the variable "showButton" when i route to "my-timesheet" and hide it when routing to other routes. i don't know how to do it cause i am new to angular.
Any help please?
PS: routing works fine

parent component html :

```
  <div class="myt-left">
        <div class="row">
           <div class="col-sm text-right ">
        <span *ngIf="
        timesheetStatus.edit
          " class="myt-unselected-tab" routerLink="my-timesheet" 
       routerLinkActive="myt-selected">
      {{ t.my_timesheet }}
       </span>
            <span *ngIf="
  timesheetStatus.review
    " class="myt-unselected-tab" routerLink="timesheet" routerLinkActive="myt-selected">
      {{ t.timesheet }}
    </span>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm text-center">
    <span class="myt-unselected-tab" routerLink="attached-files" routerLinkActive="myt-selected">
      {{ t.attachments }}
    </span>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm ">
    <span class="myt-unselected-tab" routerLink="comment" [routerLinkActive]="'myt-selected'">
      {{ t.comments }} ({{ commentsNumber }})
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
<hr class="myt-line" />
<br />

<!------  show this button when routing to my-timesheet------>
<button *ngIf="showButton">Sauvegarder</button>

 <div>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Why are you not having that button inside "my-timesheet" ?
Otherwise you can  inject `router` in constructor of parent component and then write `this.router.url` to know the route

Comment: it has to be there, when i used "this.router.url" it gives the default route but it dosent detect other routes

Comment: It will tell you which route you are on.
i feel this is not the right approach to handle this situation.

Comment: when i putted "console.log(this.router.url)" in constructor or in ngOnInit method, it gives me the first url when entering the page. when i change route it prints nothing

Comment: Ah , i get it , that's because its in parent component and parent component is not getting initialized every time, you will need to subscribe to route change events , and listen to 'NavigationEnd', that will tell you the route every time, route changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in Paren Component.ts here

```
import { Router, NavigationEnd } from '@angular/router';
export class ParentCompontent {
constructor(public router: Router) {

this.router.events.subscribe(events => {
  if (events instanceof NavigationEnd) {
    this.active = router.url;
  }
}); 
}
```

And then in ParentComponent html

```
<span *ngIf="active.includes('my-timesheet')">
  {{ t.my_timesheet }}
   </span>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get it from `ActivatedRoute` api. It has the url which you can compare with the desired route and then you can show / hide accordingly.

> https://angular.io/api/router/ActivatedRoute#description

Comment: the variable is in the parent component how can i detect route change and set it in the parent component?

Comment: If you observe the URL, you should be able to capture any changes there and assign to a variable in parent component.

Comment: how can i observe the url

Comment: @almaelghoul - You can subscribe to `this.route.url` and then assign it to some variable. For an example, please visit the link I mentioned earlier. It shows how to get an observable in the `constructor`. Please subscribe to it and it will show you the URL.